# Is there a bug with couch-nano changesReader batching, or have I missed something?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

This concerns the [`changesReader` API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#reading-changes-feed) of the couchdb-nano library.

##### Expected Behavior

I would expect the following code to wait 10 seconds and then return a batch of messages from the last position in the changes feed. So if I updated the DB 5 times within that 10 second timeout I would expect to see: "a batch of 5 changes has arrived" after 10 seconds.

```
messages.changesReader
  .start({ timeout: 10000 })
  .on('batch', (batch) => {
    console.log('a batch of', batch.length, 'changes has arrived');
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error('error', e);
  });
```

##### Current Behavior

What is happening is that no batching is taking place. Every time I update the database within that timeout I *immediately* get the log "a batch of 1 changes has arrived".

Have I missed something obvious or misunderstood how nano's batching works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with nano.  The super short answer is to use `get` but even then your interpretation of `timeout` (which seems much more like a pause or accumulate) is flawed.

Consider the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#reading-changes-feed) for `start`

> (start) to listen to changes indefinitely by repeated "long poll"
> requests. This mode continues to poll for changes forever.

OK that's clear, `start` polls "indefinitely".  The `timeout` documentation states

> The number of milliseconds a changes feed request waits for data

So `timeout` does *not apply* when using `start`.  Yes, the documentation could be less puzzling.

When does `timeout` apply? Here's the `get` method documentation

> (get) to listen to changes until the end of the changes feed is reached, by repeated "long poll" requests. Once a response with zero changes is received, the 'end' event will indicate the end of the changes and polling will stop.

In other words if X milliseconds transpire without a change event, `get` polling  concludes with the `end` event (maybe `spool` as well - I didn't test).

Consider the node script below, which demonstrates the behavior with `get`.  The `end` event will occur 10 seconds after the last batch event fires.

Here's an example output

```bash
$ node nano.js
Processing start 3:38:00 PM
a batch of 1 changes has arrived at 3:38:01 PM
a batch of 2 changes has arrived at 3:38:01 PM
a batch of 4 changes has arrived at 3:38:05 PM
a batch of 1 changes has arrived at 3:38:05 PM
a batch of 1 changes has arrived at 3:38:08 PM
Processing ended at 3:38:18 PM
```

Note the script ended 10 seconds (the timeout) after the **last** event.

If one were to replace `get` with `start`, the `end` event never fires.

```js
const nano = require("nano")("http://uid:pwd@127.0.0.1:5984");
const db = nano.db.use("my_scratch_db");
const nowstr = () => new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

console.log(`Processing start ${nowstr()}`);

(async () => {
    db.changesReader
        .get({ timeout: 10000 })
        .on("batch", (b) => {
            console.log("a batch of", b.length, `changes has arrived at ${nowstr()}`);
        })
        .on("end", (e) => {
            console.log(`Processing ${nowstr()}`);
        })
        .on("error", (e) => {
            console.error("error", (e || "no reason given").toString());
        });
})();

setTimeout(() => {
    // insert some docs, one at a time
    const docs = [{ a: 1 }];
    db.bulk({ docs });
    db.bulk({ docs });
    db.bulk({ docs });
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
    // insert a batch of docs
    const docs = [{ a: 3 }, { a: 4 }, { a: 5 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 7 }];
    db.bulk({ docs });
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
    // insert one last doc
    const docs = [{ a: 1 }];
    db.bulk({ docs });
}, 8000);
```

**Update**

I thought it important to add that the feed responses can vary depending on the disposition of the server and client.  For example, a subsequent run the above script produced compact batch responses:

```bash
Processing start 4:54:34 PM
a batch of 3 changes has arrived at 4:54:35 PM
a batch of 5 changes has arrived at 4:54:39 PM
a batch of 1 changes has arrived at 4:54:42 PM
Processing ended at 4:54:52 PM
```

Comment: Smashing. Thanks. I'll read through this tomorrow. Many thanks for such a comprehensive answer.